# CSS: making certain div sections NOT full width

Tags: html, css

I'm working on this website: docksteaderlending.ca.

I had several text blocks in the page that I didn't want to be full width, so I used this piece of css:

```
div.textwidget{
    width: 500px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

div.textwidget {
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

However, this changed all the text blocks. Initially it wasn't a big deal, but I've realized it's messed up the text blocks I have in the footer.

I'm quite new to css/html so i'm not sure how I can exclude certain text blocks.

I tried replacing textwidget with the name of the text block (ex. text-2) but that hasn't worked.

All help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Submit also you HTML code please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just apply a class to the text blocks which you want to be affected and set up a CSS rule for that class (not for the `textwidget` class)

```css
div.myclass {
  width: 500px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

div.myclass {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="myclass">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium
    quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu.</p>
  <p>In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat
    vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus.</p>
</div>
<div class="notmyclass">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium
    quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu.</p>
  <p>In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat
    vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if I understand the title "making certain div sections NOT full width"... You are trying to get different widths from a certain DIV? If so, I think what you should be doing is have multiple child divs inside THAT div and give them different width. Let me know if I understood right so I can give my best on helping out!